# How does this Decimal to Binary conversion program work?

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I was looking for an easy program for the decimal to binary conversion and then, came across the following program using recursion.

```
void bin(unsigned n)
{
/* step 1 */
if (n > 1)
    bin(n/2);

/* step 2 */
printf("%d", n % 2);
}

int main(void)
{
bin(4);
return 0;    
}
```

The output of this program was `100` as expected. But, I'm unable to understand how does it show the output `100` because according to me, the output should be `1` (incorrect) instead of `100`.

Here is my interpretation of steps of the `bin` function.

1. We will put `4` as an argument of `bin` first.
2. `4 > 1`, therefore, it will again call the `bin` function with the argument 2.
3. Now, `2 > 1`, therefore, it will again call the `bin` function with the argument 1.
4. Since `1` is not greater than `1`, we will go to step `2` and the compiler will print `1` (since `1%2=1`) and hence, this program should print `1` only and not `100`.

Can anyone please explain and guide me where I am wrong?

Comment: Use your *debugger* and single-step through the program. You'll see quickly why and when the zeros are printed.

Comment: The program uses recursion logic. Please go through recursion for more details.

Comment: The only thing *decimal* in this snippet is the `printf("%d", n % 2);` (which should have been `printf("%u", n % 2);`, BTW)

Comment: @wildplasser, `n%2` is binary `0000...01` or `0000..00` so `%u` is unnecessary.

Comment: I meant: the `"%d"` is the only thing in the program that refers to a decimal number system.

Comment: @wildplasser You mean `printf("%c", "01"[n&1]);`, right? ;)

Comment: @unwind: no, I just wanted to point at the OP's (false) understanding that the program *converts decimal to binary* . There is no decimal involved, except in the "%d", where it does not need to be decimal, because only 0 and 1 are used (which is illustrated by your `%c` example)

Comment: The user clearly showed that he tried to do this, why downvote, he is trying to learn and trying.

Comment: But the actual *decimal to binary conversion* takes place in the compiler, where the (decimal) numeric literal `4` (in `bin(4);`) is translated to the binary representation that the machine requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the illustrated sequence will make it easier for you to understand:

- `bin(4)`

  - `bin(2)`

    - `bin(1)`

      - `printf("%d",1%2); // 1`
    - `printf("%d",2%2); // 0`
  - `printf("%d",4%2); // 0`

Comment: I understand this sequence shown by you but the thing which I am not able to digest is how the second and third printf statements, whose outputs are 0 came up after printing 1. Is it because we are seeing the stack implementation here like push and pop or is there any other reason?

Comment: @DG4: `bin(2)` executes the two bullets below it. `bin(4)` executes the two bullets below it. Do you understand now?

Comment: No, I am asking about the printf statements containing 2%2 and 4%2.

Comment: @DG4: `bin(2)` calls `bin(2/2)` and then `printf("%d",2%2)`. Similarly, `bin(4)` calls `bin(4/2)` and then `printf("%d",4%2)`. Do you understand now?

Comment: Yes, I understand now what you said. But now, I have another doubt. As you said that it will print 1 first. So, after printing it, how the other two 0's are printed. Are they stored in stack below the printf statement which is printing 1?

Comment: @DG4: `bin(1)` completes, and then `bin(2)` continues. Then `bin(2)` completes, and then `bin(4)` continues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135192/discussion-between-dg4-and-barak-manos).

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track,

1. We will put 4 as an argument of bin first.
2. bin(4): 4 > 1, therefore, it will again call the bin function with the argument 2. Function execution is not complete yet. Program will return here once the called function is executed
3. bin(2): Now, 2 > 1, therefore, it will again call the bin function with the argument 1. Function execution is not complete yet. Program will return here once the called function is executed
4. bin(1): Since 1 is not greater than 1, we will go to step 2 and the compiler will print 1 (since 1%2=1) and hence, this program should print "1". Fcuntion execution complete
5. bin(2): program now returns to the caller function and prints 0(since 2%2=0). function execution complete
6. bin(4): program now returns to the caller function and prints 0(since 2%2=0). function execution complete

Hence the ouput is '100'

Comment: in your answer after the 4th step, how is it possible that the program will return to the caller function with a new value  after printing out the value '1'? My second question is are you treating it as a stack in which we are seeing the push and pop like things to print the values of the function?

Comment: When you call any function(lets say fun()) from your main function then doesnt the program controll returns to the main function after executing `fun()`? Same thing happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing an integer by 2 is the same as shifting it right one bit. So using recursion, it shifts the bits to the right until only 1 bit is left (the leftmost bit)

Then it prints this leftmost bit and returns. Upon return, there are still two bits, the leftmost and one-before-leftmost. With the `% 2` it discards all leftmost bits and prints this one-before-leftmost. Now it returns and... etc.

This effectively prints the bits left-to-right.

Comment: Ogilivie While shifting the bits to  right, shall we rotate the rightmost bit to become the leftmost or completely eliminate it?

Comment: Don't rotate it. Your recursion will never end.

Comment: If we are not rotating it then how will it find the other two bits. For eg. If I am taking 7 instead of 4, then its binary representation is 111. After first divide by 2, it will become 011; after second, it will become 001. Then after printing 1, the only bits left are two 0's. From where will it find the other two 1's?

Comment: It finds them upon the return from the recursion. _I strongly suggest you step this through a debugger so you can see what happens!_

Answer (score 0):

With your logic:

```
somefunc();
someotherfunc();
```

When `somefunc()` is finished doing it's thing, `someotherfunc()` will not be executed since `somefunc()` was done.

What happens is that step 2 is done when the call to `bin` is done or not run at all and then step 2 is always done. Thus Every iteration of `bin` prints something and since it's **after** the recursion it does it from the deepest and and up making the printing in reverse order from the actual recursive path.

Every call to `bin`has it's own local variables so they don't interfere with each other. Thus when the call to `bin` from `bin` is done `n` is the same as before but the returning `bin` had a `n` that was half of the caller's `n`.

Comment: Can you please explain why it will recurse it from the deepest or will print in the reverse order rather than the actual recursive path as you said. I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @DG4 It's because it does statements it in the order you write it. If you move the print statement before the conditional recursion it will print it in the reverse order since it prints the lowest bit first, then recurse. Since your version recurses first and wait for **every depth** to print before this iteration and that you always print the lowest bit it prints the highest bit to lowest, thus in oposite order of the recursive path which the first iteration is for the lowest bit, the next is for the next lowest ... the highest.